# not converting 24 hour format in ipad only

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, nsdateformatter

Hi everyone in my project i want to convert the Date & time(12 hr) into time only(24 hr) it working in iphone & ipod but i run in the iPad it not converting correctly what is the problem.

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateformatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss a";
    NSString *st=dictt[@"DATE_TIME"];//29-OCT-2016 09:25:52 AM  -- this is input
    NSDate *date = [dateformatter dateFromString:st];
    NSDateFormatter *dateformatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateformatter1.dateFormat = @"HH:mm:ss";
    NSString *time24 = [dateformatter1 stringFromDate:date];//9:25:52 am -- this is output
```

but in iPhone it gives 9:25:52 correctly in iphone

Comment: Would i be right in saying your iPad is set for 12hr time in its locale settings and your iPhone is set for 24hr?

Comment: Yes.i changed the time format to 24 hrs in ipad means it gives correctly

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the locale as per https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1480/_index.html

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateformatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a";

// set locale
dateformatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]; 

NSString *st=dictt[@"DATE_TIME"];//29-OCT-2016 09:25:52 AM  -- this is input
NSDate *date = [dateformatter dateFromString:st];
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateformatter1.dateFormat = @"HH:mm:ss";
NSString *time24 = [dateformatter1 stringFromDate:date];//9:25:52 am -- this is output
```

Comment: you dont want `dd-MM-YYYY` but `dd-MM-yyyy`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
Formatter.locale = NSLocale.systemLocale()
```

this will help you